# Inline divs with vertical lists

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, html-lists

I'm trying to design a footer section for my website, and I'm having trouble with cross-browser compatible solutions. I need a way to display inline divs with vertical lists inside them. eg.

```
Div 1     Div 2
.li one   .li one
.li two   .li two
          .li three
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your example isn't clear. Why are the divs necessary when you have two lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example using floats and a simple `clear:both;` hack to keep the divs inside say your footer...

**CSS:**

```
.foot-box {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="foot-box">
<ul>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="foot-box">
<ul>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="foot-box">
<ul>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YASU5/

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of @Jakub answer, you can do it without needing to float either.

CSS:

```
.foot-box {
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="foot-box">
<ul>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="foot-box">
<ul>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="foot-box">
<ul>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
 <li>element</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It will allow the lists to have different number of items too.

http://jsfiddle.net/XHtnU/

Comment: The reason I went with floats, is due to lack of IE6/7 support for `inline-block` => http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Just providing another alternative. Maybe they don't support that far back. `:)`

Comment: Isn't this awfully complicated for two lists?